# Communication with current displayed Fragment using BroadCast Reciever Vs Listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an `Activity` that displays different `Fragments` and these `fragments` changed when the user select an `item` from the `spinner` in the `ActionBar` , I have refresh `button` on the `ActionBar` . If i want to tell the current displayed fragment to refresh it content using the refresh menu button on the ActionBar . should i implement a Listener that communicates with Fragments ? or should i use a `BroadCastReciever` to inform the Fragment to refresh . Which is better ?? i haven't implement any of these .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really not easy question.
From one side, Broadcast probably will be an overkill for such a simple task, so I'd recommend to use listeners. But..

But please, be sure you understand how Fragments work. If you intent to create them from code and immediately set listeners - that can work for first time. But you can have troubles with activity recreation, when system re-instantiates a fragment. In this case it can just use Fragment's public empty constructor and your code can go wrong with listeners not-setted.

So I think the good idea will be to set listeners from Fragment itself, for example in `onAttach()` or `onStart`. There you can get holding activity with `getActivity()` and set listeners. The cons of this approach is that you must cast your Activity to specific class to access listener-methods, and this limits the fragment reusage in other Activities, so beware this fact.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You should only use broadcasting if you need to "talk" to wider audience. In you case you want one fragment and one button and I suggest implementing listeners. It can be either activity listening to action bar button action and then telling fragment to refresh, or bind these two directly